# Why can't a div in aspx file fill in whole screen in ASP.net file?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

The Code A is a aspx file, I hope that the div with `id="container"` fill in whole screen, but I only get Image A, and the div with `id="container"` is only a little height, what's wrong with my code?

**Code A**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="aa.aspx.cs" Inherits="LinkTabs.aa" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div id="container">
             Hello World!
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>

body {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;   
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Image A
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the default WebForms "form" that is added. You need to set that height to 100% also. And set the height of `html` also to 100%, the same as `body`.

```
<style>
     html, body {
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #form1 {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```